# ELK stack over SSL?

Tags: ssl, elastic-stack

I have successfully installed Elasticsearch, Logstash, Kibana and Nginx on an ubuntu 14 server, everything is working perfectly but i want Logstash and Kibana to use SSL encryption, i have bought a commercial SSL Certificate, and i got 3 files :

1. Domain.crt
2. Domain.key
3. Domain.ca

I have tried to upload the files to the /etc/pki/tls folder and point to them from kibana.yml but it didn't work.

How can i use these files to create a secure ssl on the server ?

Comment: Please explain which part of the communication you want to be encrypted: 1) Logstash (are you using the lumberjack input), 2) Logstash -> Elasticsearch, 3) Elasticsearch <-> Kibana and/or 4) Browser <-> Kibana ?